# Java Spring How to invoke @PreDestroy when windows shuts down?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I run the application from the command line and I need the method to be executed and send a post request when Windows shuts down

@PreDestroy - It only works if I end the application manually. Is it possible to somehow call the method in the code when windows shuts down?

I already tried to prescribe in the configuration server.shutdown: graceful

Or maybe there is another way to call the method before Windows shuts down?

Comment: I think PreDestroy will be automatically called even if you shut down windows..

Comment: I run the application from the command line, press shutdown computer and no query that should be executed in the method marked with @PreDestroy is executed. But if I try to terminate the app with ctrl+c everything works

Comment: Did you run with javaw.exe ?

Comment: no, just in console

Comment: i tried to wrap it in exe with launch4j, but the result didn't change - @PreDestroy didnt work